# Formatting X-Axis Time in Python

Tags: python, csv, unix, matplotlib

I'm plotting data from a text file with two columns that are delimited by a comma. The first column is time that is formatted in `%H:%S`. The second line are numbers.

Right now, the coding that I have is displaying `%Y%m%d %H:%M:%s` instead of `%H:%M`. As you can see, there are a lot of entries and they are overlapping each other. How can I make the ticks skip every 1 or 2 to make the times more visible?

How can I correct this?

**File Contents:**

```
09:30,33.89
09:34,34.17
09:39,34.41
09:44,34.20
09:49,34.40
```

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import division
import sys
import csv
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np

homedir = '/home//'

ymd = sys.argv[1]
sym = sys.argv[2]

x,y = [],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open(homedir + 'finance/data/' + sym + '_' + ymd))
for line in csv_reader:
    x.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%H:%M'))
    y.append(str(line[1]))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

#ax.grid(which='both')

ax.plot(x,y,'-',ms=3,linewidth=1)
#fig.autofmt_xdate(x,rotation=90,ha='center')
plt.xticks(x, x, rotation=90,ha='center')
plt.title('Daily Market Data for ' + sym + ' on ' + ymd)
plt.ylabel('Stock Price [$]')
plt.xlabel('Time of Day')
plt.grid(True)

fig.set_size_inches(9,5)

plt.savefig(homedir + 'finance/' + sym + '_' + ymd + '.png', dpi = 300, bbox_inches='tight')
#plt.show()
```

**Plot:**

[image]

Comment: Just re-uploaded the plot.

Comment: This may help: http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.strptime()` parses a string time to a `datetime` object using the second argument to map the values from the original string to the `datetime` components. Here's a couple guides explaining the difference between [strptime()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strptime.htm) and [strftime()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_strftime.htm).

Anyways, I guess you could just use the original strings for your `xticks` and leave the line that builds the `x` list for your plot alone, since it seems to work adequately.

Try changing your `for` loop section to this:

```
x,y,xticks = [],[],[]
csv_reader = csv.reader(open(homedir + 'finance/data/' + sym + '_' + ymd))
for line in csv_reader:
    xticks.append(line[0])
    x.append(dt.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%H:%M'))
    y.append(str(line[1]))
```

Then, of course, get rid of your other `xticks` assignment and change your `plt.xticks` call to this:

```
plt.xticks(x, xticks, rotation=90,ha='center')
```

Edit: OP added to the question, I'll give some brief advice.

Maybe do something hacky in your `for` loop like

```
for line in csv_reader:
    time = dt.datetime.strptime(line[0], '%H:%M')
    if time.minute % 5 == 0:
        xticks.append(line[0])
    else:
        xticks.append("")
    x.append(time)
    y.append(str(line[1]))
```

Comment: Hi Jason. Thank you for the reply! I forgot to mention that I want the x axis to be the `%H:%M` times, not what I had defined in the xticks array. Still getting %Y%m%d %H:%M:%s instead of %H:%M...

Comment: Did you get rid of the line where you made your `xticks` list? Notice in the `for` loop in my answer it is loading up a new, empty `xticks` list. Now for the other problem you just added to your question, I'll make an edit.

Comment: Doh! Forgot to delete the previously-defined xticks array. This worked perfectly for getting the %Y%m%d %H:%M:%s down to just %H:%M!